# How can I Turn on/off Accessibility through appium using javascript

Tags: javascript, appium, accessibility, appium-android, talkback

I have this adb shell command for android and tried with the terminal and it's working perfectly.

But not sure how to use this in a framework using appium command.

```
// disable
adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services com.android.talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService

// enable
adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services com.google.android.marvin.talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec('adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services com.google.android.marvin.talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
          return;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to use abd command in java in the following way. Hope its helps you too.

```
String disable= "adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services com.android.talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService"
String enable = "adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services com.google.android.marvin.talkback/com.google.android.marvin.talkback.TalkBackService"
try{
       Runtime.getRuntime().exec(disable); //to disable
   //    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(enable);  //to enable
}catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: it's helpful. thank you very much. But I'm trying to do it using node.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mobile:shell](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-shell/) in Appium to execute **ADB commands**:

You must start Appium server with security key:

`appium --relaxed-security`

Then you do it like:

```
List<String> args = Arrays.asList(
   arg1,
   arg2,
   ...
   argN
);
Map<String, Object> yourCmd = ImmutableMap.of(
    "command", <adbCommand>,
    "args", args
);
driver.executeScript("mobile: shell", yourCmd);
```

I'm not sure about `settings put` operation, but `pull`/`push`/`rm` works perfectly.